# Running airodump-ng from script

Tags: linux, airodump-ng

I am trying to write a script that runs airodump-ng.
I use the command:

```
timeout -sHUP 1m airodump-ng -d MYBSSID -w wpahandshake wlan0mon
```

when I run it from the command line it works but when i run it from a script it creates a empty .cap file. 
Do someone have an explanation to why and a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug existing in airodump-ng 1.2 rc4 (Released 14 Feb 2016) to airodump-ng 1.2 (Released 15 Apr 2018).

But in 18 Apr 2018, the GitHub user Mister-X fixed the problem. See the [commit](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng/commit/a2009a0549ba30af4455ec208ac319f895dec3b4).

In `src/airodump-ng.c` with the bug, it will use `input_thread()` to create a thread regardless of whether the airodump-ng process running in the foreground or background.

The `input_thread()` will call `mygetch()`. And the `mygetch()` will call `getchar()`. Thus airodump-ng process will read stdin when running in the background.

In Linux, if a process reads stdin when running in the background, it will be stopped. And running `timeout` without `--foreground` option will let the `COMMAND`, here is airodump-ng, run in the background. So in this situation, the airodump-ng will be stopped and create a empty .cap file (asked by you).

There are two lines of thinking to solve your problem:

1. Let the airodump-ng run in the foreground by using `--foreground` option of `timeout` or running `source <your_orignal_script.sh>`.
2. Don't let the airodump-ng read stdin when running in background by redirecting stdin to /dev/null, `timeout -sHUP 1m airodump-ng -d MYBSSID -w wpahandshake wlan0mon < /dev/null` or downloading the newest source code without the bug from GitHub then compile and install it.

Comment: I maneged to get it working by issuing `echo "airodump-ng -d MYBSSID -w wpahandshake wlan0mon" | bash - `